# form validation not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am writing a simple GUI using netbeans and Java SE, i cannot seem to get input validation to work correctly. I have a JTextField and 2 JPasswordField objects, I want to check that any of these fields arent empty when the user hits the submit button. It works properly for the password fields if they are left empty, however if i input something into the username field, it prints data has been submitted, when the other form elements have not been filled with data. Here is the code below, any assistance would be greatly appreciated....

```
// test that none of the fields are empty before submitting form data
if (!username_input.getText().isEmpty() && !password_input1.getPassword().toString().isEmpty() 
                && !password_input2.getPassword().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Data has been submitted!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Form has not been filled in correctly!\nPlease try again");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like

```
!username_input.getText().toString().equals("")&& 
!new String(password_input1.getPassword()).equals("") &&
!new String(password_input2.getPassword()).equals("")
```

Comment: For security reasons, `getText` is **deprecated**. Use the `getPassword` method instead.

Comment: @PaulVargas Updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `boolean expression` to:

```
!username_input.getText().isEmpty() && 
password_input1.getPassword().lenght == 0 &&   
password_input2.getPassword().lenght == 0
```

The method `getPassword()` returns a `char array` and you need check the `lenght == 0` for empty values in the `JPasswordField`.

Comment: thanks, i actually managed to figure that out before coming back to read this lol, kinda weird how they fill the password fields with data, even though they are technically of length 0... do you happen to know the reason behind this?

Comment: @MatthewPigram `password_input1.getPassword().toString()` is actually toString() invoked on char[]. It probably just prints a reference of the array. So it is never empty.